# Best Java Script Plugin for Image compression with many browsers support

Tags: javascript

Can someone suggest a best Java Script Plugin for Image compression with many browsers support?

I searched and find many and not sure about the drawbacks and advantages of using it.

If someone already uses it, please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: When do you want to compress the image - when receiving it or when sending it?

Comment: User will browse and upload the image of any size and i need to compress it and send it. The compression should happen in the browser side and not in the server side.

Comment: You can do it if browser has html5 support. Older browsers cannot do this without flash support. And I don't think flash support is as available now a days. In some browsers the user needs to enable it from browser settings. I can help if you consider the html5 approach.

Comment: sure. please kindly help me with html5 approach with code snippet if possible...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write you own code with HTML5 Canvas, file and Blob Url. 
All this code will take half of screen). If you working with very large images, e.g. 6000x9000 for better quality you should use this lib
 https://github.com/nodeca/pica instead of canvas.
This is most powerful lib that i know at js. Lib with several resize algorithms for people who knnow the difference.